# maven-version-rules.xml - how to process only some artifacts?

Tags: maven, maven-versions-plugin

Maven versions plugin can use maven-version-rules.xml file to filter out unwanted versions of specific artifacts. So it works more like a blacklist.

I would like to process only artifacts with their package name starting with com.xxx.yyy

Is it possible?